# log4j2 file not writing to file

Tags: java, log4j2

I've been searching the web for days now but somehow nothing seems to help.
I try to migrate from log4j 1.x to log4j 2 but something is not right here and I hope one of you can help.

I have a JSF application running on Websphere 8 and this is is my configuration so far:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration>
    <Filter type="ThresholdFilter" level="trace"/>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="DEBUG" filePattern="C:/Files/varm_debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" fileName="C:/Files/varm_debug.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} ;%-5p; [%c{1}.%M]; %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1500KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="INFO" filePattern="C:/Files/varm_info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" fileName="C:/Files/varm_info.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} ;%-5p; [%c{1}.%M]; %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1500KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="WARN" filePattern="C:/Files/varm_warn.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" fileName="C:/Files/varm_warn.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} ;%-5p; [%c{1}.%M]; %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="ERROR" filePattern="C:/Files/varm_error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" fileName="C:/Files/varm_error.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} ;%-5p; [%c{1}.%M]; %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>


        <File name="comparisonLogAppender" fileName="C:/Files/VARM-output.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601}; %m%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <!-- Logger to compare results -->

        <!--  Logger to log infos/errors throughout comparison -->
        <Logger name="comparisonLogger" level="trace"  additivity="true" immediateFlush="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="comparisonLogAppender"/>

        </Logger>

        <Logger name="de.saltsolutions.varm" level="info" >
            <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG" level="debug"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="INFO" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="WARN" level="warn"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR" level="error"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn">
                    <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG" level="debug"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="INFO" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="WARN" level="warn"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR" level="error"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG" level="debug"/>
        </Root>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="INFO" level="info"/>
        </Root>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="WARN" level="warn"/>
        </Root>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR" level="error"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

All the files are generated okay but they stay empty.
My main problem is the comparisonLogger. If I use it (LogManager.getLogger("comparisonLogger") in my main class, it writes the log file perfectly.
But when I try using the exact same logger in my ManagedBean (ViewScoped) nothing gets logged.

Does anybody know why it doesn't work in my ManagedBean? Does this have anything to do with the Websphere?

I hope anybody can help because I have absolutely no idea what I could possibly do to make this work.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Have you made sure to check the `Websphere` logs to see if the `log4j2` complains about anything being wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out my problems.

1. I use Log4j2 in a web application which means that I needed to add some stuff in my web.xml (further information here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)
2. You can only configure ONE root logger

Once I adjusted that, everything worked just as expected.

My Log4j2 Jar-Files are now in my client and my ear and my XML config is in my client but it also works if you split the config files (one part in my web project the other for the client on C:\temp or some other directory)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put the log4j2 jar files and log4j2.xml config in a place so that they are always in the classpath.